# jQuery form submit and change value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to change a value form a model and submit it back to the server so i can process the changes.

here is my javascript which the alerts are diplaying the value before the change and after the change. but when it is submitted the value that i change with the javascript does not change.

```
    function sort(field)
    {
        var description = $('#ProductFilterForm input[name="DescriptionSort"]');
        var form = $('#ProductFilterForm');
        alert(description.val());
        switch (field) {
            case "Description":
                var desc = description.val() == 'a' ? 'd' : 'a';
                description.val(desc);
                break;
        }
        alert(description.val());
        form.submit();
    }
```

Comment: `$(description.val(desc));` ?? don't need it, just `description.val(desc);` ..

Comment: try this `description.attr('value',desc);`

Comment: still will not submit with changed values

Comment: You should watch the network traffic, because it looks like it works to me.